# can you solve the problem? Python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets

i have 2 python programs which speak with sockets.
The First one i have called **"King.py"**:

```
import os
import time
import sys
import socket

i = 0
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print("hostname: " + host)
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
print("")
print("Auf Verbindungen warten.")
print("")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("")
print(addr, " - Ist dem Server beigetreten.")
print("")

while i < 1:
    command = input(str("Command : "))
    conn.send(command.encode())
    print("Der Befehl wurde gesendet, warte auf Akzeptierung")
    print("")
    result = s.recv(1024)
    result = result.decode()
    if result:
        print(result)
```

and the second one i have called **"noobie.py"**:

```
import time
import sys
import socket
import os
import subprocess

i = 0
s = socket.socket()
host = "realMxrlxn-PC"
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))
print("")
print(" Connected to server ")

while i < 1:
    command = s.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    if not command == "dir":
        os.system(command)
    else:
        result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
        conn.send(result.encode())
```

So now i want you to ask why im getting the **"WinError 10057"** in king.py, because it says i have no socket? (result = s.recv(1024))

Comment: You should receive on a connection, not on a socket.

Comment: Try `conn.recv(1024)`

Comment: thanks boys :) now its working, but there are much files, i must write more than once "dir" lol but its ok :)

Comment: Raw socket programming is difficult. For instance, you should use `sendall` or add to code to make up for the fact that fewer bytes might be sent than you want. You also have a problem with `recv` - it grabs what happens to be there, not exactly what was sent. I like the `zeromq` messaging service. It has a robust way to work with messages and to deal with complex flows. https://zeromq.org/